# How to filter after two joins in flask SQL alchemy

Tags: python, join, sqlalchemy, subquery, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following 3 tables:

```
class Sample(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
    all_prosampairs = db.relationship('Prosampair', order_by="Prosampair.order", backref='modifies_sample', lazy=True, cascade="all, delete", passive_deletes=True)

class Process(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    ...
    all_prosampairs = db.relationship('Prosampair', backref='in_process', lazy=True, cascade="all, delete", passive_deletes=True)

class Prosampair(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    order = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    ...
    process_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('process.id', ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False)
    sample_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sample.id', ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False)
```

Each sample has a chain of processes it goes through and I need to get a table which includes both Sample.id and the latest date it has encountered a process, so that I can filter by this date.

[Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Pe8P.png)

What I tried so far was looking at this and similar solutions:

https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/nested-queries-with-sqlalchemy-orm

But I can't quite comprehend how to deal with this third association table that I have yet.

```
 subqjoin1 = db.session.query(Sample).join(Prosampair).join(Process).subquery()
 subqjoin2 = db.session.query(subqjoin1, db.func.max(Process.date).label('latest_process')).group_by(Sample.id).subquery()
 result = db.session.query(subqjoin2).filter( subqjoin2.c.latest_process <= value ).all()
```

I am getting variations of

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: sample.id
```

and I am afraid I don't quite grasp how to access the parameters that I want to. Two subqueries are probably excessive, but I struggle to figure out a better way

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Please in code questions give a [mre]. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to reference columns in the subquery off of `.c`, for example `subq.c.latest_process`.

```py
with Session(engine) as session:
    latest_subq = session.query(
        Sample.id.label("sample_id"),
        func.max(Process.date).label("latest_process")
    ).outerjoin(
        Prosampair, Sample.id == Prosampair.sample_id
    ).outerjoin(
        Process, Prosampair.process_id == Process.id
    ).group_by(
        Sample.id
    ).subquery()

    q = session.query(Sample, latest_subq.c.latest_process).join(latest_subq, Sample.id == latest_subq.c.sample_id).order_by(latest_subq.c.latest_process)

    for sample, latest_process in q.all():
        print (sample.id, latest_process)
```